# How to access mysql database from another host machine

Tags: mysql

I am trying to access mysql database from another host machine . My Java Application is hosted on one system and database hosted on another system .I am unable to access database from application hosted machin.

changing IP address of both machine its now working.
error occurred.

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: "Host 'IBM-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

Comment: Have a thorough look at the configuration file

Comment: yes you mean using bind-address ?Yes i tried that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is root to connect to MySQL on any hosts. By default, user “root” was only allowed to connect to localhost and 127.0.0.1 hosts of MySQL.

And you can try it;

```
#GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘root’@’%’ 
IDENTIFIED BY ‘<roots-password>’ WITH GRANT OPTION;
```